# Laravel 5 query counting and grouping

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I need some help in my report generation.

My table structure is like:

```
flight_no  year  month ....  ...

402        2016    1
402        2016    1
403        2016    1
402        2016    2
403        2016    2
403        2016    2
403        2016    3
```

I want a annual report group by months and by counting how many flight flown on each month with flight number. I am doing this in laravel.

I tried:

```
$total_scheduled = DB::table('schedule_details')
                            ->select('id','flight_id','year','month' 
                                    DB::raw('count(id) as total_sch')
                              )
                            ->where('year','2016')
                            ->groupBy('month')
                            ->get();
```

It gives me the total flight but I am confuse in getting all flight number for each month for e.g.:

> month 1
>   total_sc = 3
>   flight nos =402,403
>
> month 2
>   total_sc = 3
>   flight nos =402,403
>
> month 3
>   total_sc = 1
>   flight nos =403

Answer (score 0):

I can solve this problem in following way but I need this in one query is this possible??

```
$month_schs = ScheduleDetail::where('year','2016')
                                    ->groupBy('month')->get(['year', 'month']);

  foreach($month_schs as $month_sch){

     echo '<b>'.$month_sch->year.'-'.$month_sch->month.'</b><br>';

     $flight_nos = ScheduleDetail::where('year',$month_sch->year)
                                ->where('month',$month_sch->month)
                                ->groupBy('flight_number')
                                ->get(['flight_number']);



        foreach($flight_nos as $flight_no){

                  echo '<b>'.$flight_no->flight_number.'</b><br>';


        }

}
```